Worker service in .NET Core 8 C# Serilog logger : write to file using setting in AppSettings
I want to add Serilog for logging and write the log into text file based setting defined in the appsettings.json config file.
I find challenge since .NET Core 8 it uses
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

The sample I get most uses
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

I want to define complete settings in appsettings.json and worker service must read from that and behave accordingly.
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "log.txt", "rollingInterval": "Day" } }
    ]
  }
}

Please help me to provide the config from appsettings.json and program.cs where code is registered.
Found solution
builder.Services.AddSerilog(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
        .WriteTo.File(logFilePath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
            fileSizeLimitBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024) // Limit each log file to 10 MB
);

Here I want to log only for Information, Warning. I tried "Where" but it says that method is not available though I have serilog 3.0
And Also I added custom Logger to log Error and critical to SQL Server Database Table via proc. I made that changes it is not working both. It write to file when both are enabled. if I comment serilog the it write to sql server table. Please advise
builder.Services.AddSerilog(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
    .WriteTo.File(logFilePath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
        fileSizeLimitBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024) // Limit each log file to 10 MB

);
var connectionString = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");
var sqlServerMinimumLogLevel = Configuration.GetValue<LogLevel>("Logging:SqlServerMinimumLevel", LogLevel.Error); // Default to Error

builder.Services.AddLogging(configure =>
{
    configure.AddProvider(new SqlServerLoggerProvider(connectionString.Value, sqlServerMinimumLogLevel) ); // Assuming custom provider implemented
}); 

Another Challenge I face it is write to text file but not writting to database table using custom log provider.
I want both Serilog to write text and use custom log provider to write into database table. Please advise

So what is the actual question? How to add Serilog to app using  CreateApplicationBuilder? Can you please share examples for CreateDefaultBuilder you have found?

I'm not 100% sure I understand your actual problem but my best guess is that builder.Services.AddSerilog is overriding any other log provider you add later (incl your custom Sql log provider). If you use serilog, then that's your only log provider and you are "supposed" to add different serilog log sinks to the logging pipeline, instead of multiple log providers to the aspnet core logging builder.

1.Install the necessary NuGet packages for Serilog, its sinks for file and console, and the settings configuration:
dotnet add package Serilog
dotnet add package Serilog.Sinks.Console
dotnet add package Serilog.Sinks.File
dotnet add package Serilog.Settings.Configuration
dotnet add package Serilog.Extensions.Hosting

2.Create an appsettings.json file with the Serilog configuration settings. Here’s an example of what your appsettings.json might look like:
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "log.txt" } }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "YourAppName"
    }
  }
}

3.Configure Serilog in your Program.cs or Startup.cs to use the configuration from appsettings.json:
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog();


My Project is not Worker Service and it does not have Host. var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args); there is no Host in builder. I am unbale to use this builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) => configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));

I have updated steps 1 and 3. In step 1, instead of the Serilog.AspNetCore package, I used the Serilog.Extensions.Hosting package, and in step 3, I changed the Serilog registration. @user3497702

Thanks for the update. It works. I added this in config       {
"Name": "File",
"Args": {
"path": ".\logs\log-{Date}.txt",
"fileSizeLimitBytes": 104857600, // 100 MB limit (adjust as needed)
"rollingInterval": "Day", // Use if Serilog version supports it
"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
}
}

Assign
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.CreateLogger();
Log.Logger = logger;

Here Log.Logger is globally-shared logger.

I want both Serilog to write text and use custom log provider to write into database table. both should work simultaneously. Please advise

I used the following config to to write into text file but it not working with @Gourav Saini code. Please advise
{
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
"MinimumLevel": "Information",
"WriteTo": [
{
"Name": "File",
"Args": {
"path": "logs/log.txt",
"rollingInterval": "Day",
"rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
"fileSizeLimitBytes": 10485760
}
}
]
}
}

You can you serilog sinks to write the logs in database also.
